# How to remove L.Routing.line in leaflet with Leaflet Routing Machine?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to get a function to work that updates a L.Routing.line with Leaflet Routing Machine whenever a user adds or deletes a waypoint.

My code to date (slight adaptation from http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/interaction.html):

```
function routeImplement(){
    if (routewpts.length >= 2) {
        router.route(routewpts, function(err, routes) {
            if (routeline) {
                map.removeLayer(routeline);
            };

            if (err) {
                alert(err);
            } else {
                routeline = L.Routing.line(routes[0]).addTo(map);
            };
        });
    }
    else{
        if (routeline) {
           map.removeLayer(routeline);
        };
    };
}
```

`routewpts` is an array of latLngs, `routeline` is supposed to be the L.Routing.line, `router=L.Routing.osrm();`, and `map` is the leaflet map (all globals).  The function works fine for creating a line.

The issue that I am having is that the `map.removeLayer(routeline);` doesn't seem to work.  There are two issues it seems: one is that `L.Routing.line` doesn't seem to return anything, so `routeline` is remaining undefined.  Second, if I dispense with the use of a handle, and try to use `map.removeLayer` directly on `L.Routing.line`, I get some crazy error about a bad request to OSRM.org.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... It turns out the way to get this to work is to break up the L.Routing.line call:

```
routeline = L.Routing.line(routes[0]);
routeline.addTo(map);
```

With that the routeline handle works and everything else functions fine.  I don't understand Leaflet (or the Routing Machine) well enough to explain why it gave up on returning anything if the line is immediately added to the map.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that i mooved forward is to use arrow function

```js
function routeImplement(){
    if (routewpts.length >= 2) {
        router.route(routewpts, (err, routes) => { //arrow function
            if (routeline) {
                map.removeLayer(routeline);
            };

            if (err) {
                alert(err);
            } else {
                routeline = L.Routing.line(routes[0]).addTo(map);
            };
        });
    }
    else{
        if (routeline) {
           map.removeLayer(routeline); // but still this line doesnt work for me
        };
    };
}
```